# Where is my Insaniquarium Steam Product Activation Code?

Tags: steam, insaniquarium-deluxe

Forgive me if my title was a bit wordy and confusing, but I simply want to know where my product activation code for my Insaniquarium Deluxe is. I wish to add it on Steam so that I can play it there and so that it is easier to find it (as I am very forgetful). So, where can I find my product activation code? Pictures would be nice, but not needed. I bought it from Target a few years back.

Comment: Did you buy it from Steam? From Popcap? As a CD? As a download?

Comment: @AshleyNunn sorry, added the information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you bought it from Target a few years back, it is likely that you don't actually have a Steam Activation code for the game. However, if you have the game installed on your computer, you can add it to Steam as a non-Steam game in order to make it easier for you to find on your computer.

To do that, click the "Add A Game" button on the bottom left of your Steam window.

[image]

From there, click "Add Non-Steam Game" from the list that pops up.

[image]

From there, Steam will go through your computer, and give you a list of software that you can add to the menu in your Steam Library. (Note: This does not mean you own Steam versions of the games you add this way.)

Select the games you want to add, and then click "Add Selected Programs". The games you choose will now be available from the Steam launcher.

However, if you don't have the game currently installed, or do not have a way to install the game (such as losing the original CD you have it on), then you will have to re-buy the game.

Steam does (as of Jan. 6, 2013) sell Insaniquarium, so if you have lost the CD and wish to still play the game, re-buying it might be your best bet.